# Change "via..." in outbound mass emails

Tags: email-relay

I am sending mass emails using apex class from salesforce. 
But when I get email I am getting via "etr84e4dmbqf7799.1jpogue.8-cjifeai.na6.bnc.salesforce.com".

I don't want the user to get this.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to set up [email relaying](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_relay.htm) to accomplish this. This is feature that requires you to log a case first to have the functionality enabled for your org.

This will allow Salesforce to route outgoing emails through your company's SMTP server, removing the via... in your email from address.